# Problems looking for csv values in txt file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm new to Stackoverflow and relatively new to Python. I Have tried searching the site for an answer to this question, but haven't found one related to matching values between csv and txt files.

I'm writing a simple Python script that reads in a row from large csv file (~600k lines), grabs a value from that row, assigns to a variable, then uses the variable to try to find a matching value from a large txt file (~1.8MM lines). It's not working and I'm not sure why.

Here's a snippet from the `source.csv` file:

```
DocNo,Title,DOI
1,"Title One",10.1080/02724634.2016.1269539
2,"Title Two",10.1002/2015ja021888
3,"Title Three",10.1016/j.palaeo.2016.09.019
```

Here's a snippet from the `lookup.txt` file (note that it's separated by `\t`):

```
DOI 10.1016/j.palaeo.2016.09.019    M   First
DOI 10.1016/j.radmeas.2015.12.002   M   First
DOI 10.1097/SCS.0000000000002859    M   First
```

Here's the offending code:

```
import csv

with open('source.csv', newline='', encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as f, open('lookup.txt', 'r') as i:
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel')

    counter = 0

    for line in i:
        for row in reader:
            doi = row[2]
            doi = str(doi) # I think this might actually be redundant...

            if doi in line:
                # This will eventually do more interesting things, but right now it's just a test
                print(doi)
                break
            else:
                # This will be removed--is also just a test (so I can watch progress)
                print(counter)
                counter += 1
```

Currently, when it runs, it just counts the lines, even though there's a matching `doi` in each file.

The maddening thing is that when I give `doi` a hard-coded value, it executes as it should. This makes me think that either the slashes in `doi` are breaking things somehow, or I need to convert the data type of the `doi` variable.

For example, this works:

```
doi = "10.1016/j.palaeo.2016.09.019" 

for line in i:
    if doi in line:
        print(doi)
        break
    else:
        print(counter)
        counter += 1
```

Thanks in advance for your help, I'm at my wit's end!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that repeating `for line in i:` does not start over from the beginning on each loop, but rather it keeps going where it was when you called `break` the last time. If you have any line in the lookup file `i` that has no match, you will effectively go through the lookup file completely and then all calls to `for line in i:` will do nothing (empty loop).

You probably want to keep the lookup lines in a list, as a first step. Turning it into a lookup dict by parsing the row would likely  be the next step.

Here is a demonstration of what happens:

```
!cat 1.txt
row1
row2
row3

!cat 2.txt
row A
row B
row C

with open('1.txt', 'r') as i, open('2.txt', 'r') as j:
    for irow in i:
        print "irow", irow.strip()
        for jrow in j:
            print "jrow", jrow.strip()

irow row1
jrow row A
jrow row B
jrow row C
irow row2
irow row3
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! When you say _does not start over from the beginning on each loop_, do you mean that each `line in i` won't run through all the `rows in reader`? Why not? When I try to reverse the logic (e.g. `for row in reader, doi = row[2] ... for line in i, if <match> then <do something>`) it also doesn't work. I'm obviously not grasping the logic here :/

Comment: Added a demonstration. Hopefully that shows what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import csv
data = csv.reader(open('data1.csv'))
data1 = [i.strip('\n').split()[1] for i in open('data2.txt')]
file_data = [i[-1] for i in data if i[-1] in data1]
```

Output from sample files provided:

```
['10.1016/j.palaeo.2016.09.019']
```